# missing package attribute in AndroidManifest.xml when create a project with flutter create

Tags: flutter

I created a flutter project with `flutter create chat_app` in terminal. But the package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml is missing. How to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="chat_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried `flutter create --org com.chat_app chat_app` but it didn't work.

Comment: Which `flutter --version` do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` is missing the `package` attribute, because it was removed from the `flutter` CLI tool template. It is deprecated. It was removed [in this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/123426).

> In the Gradle-based build system, starting with AGP 7.3, don't set the package value in the source manifest file directly. For more information, see Set the application ID.

— https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#package

Your `android/app/build.gradle` should have a `namespace` statement in the `android {}` with the package instead like so:

```
// ...

android {
  namespace "com.chat_app"

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow that answers my 5 hours of research. Thanks a lot!! and happy coding